# React Hook Form + Material UI Datepickers and Luxon output formatting

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, luxon

I am working on a React application using React Hook Form, Material UI, and Luxon for Date parsing.

I have made a number of form fields reusable and all work great but am having some troubles with DatePickers and output formatting.

Basically, I want to take the value of my outputted DatePicker and TimePicker and format it correctly to send to the backend.

I have the following components:

DatePicker:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Controller, useFormContext} from "react-hook-form";
import DatePicker from '@mui/lab/DatePicker';
import DateAdapter from '@mui/lab/AdapterLuxon';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import TextInput from "../TextInput/TextInput";

export const DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";

export const DateInput = ({name, label, defaultValue, ...props}) => {
    const {control, register, formState: {errors}} = useFormContext();
    return (
        <Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            render={({field}) => (
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
                    <DatePicker
                        {...field}
                        inputFormat={DATE_INPUT_FORMAT}
                        renderInput={(props) => (
                            <TextInput
                                label={label}
                                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                                {...register(name)}
                                error={!!errors[name]}
                                helperText={errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message : ''}
                                {...props}
                            />
                        )}
                        {...props}
                    />
                </LocalizationProvider>
            )}
        />
    )
};

DateInput.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    defaultValue: PropTypes.string
};

DateInput.defaultProps = {
    label: "",
    defaultValue: "",
};

export default DateInput;
```

and TimePicker:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Controller, useFormContext} from "react-hook-form";
import TimePicker from '@mui/lab/TimePicker';
import DateAdapter from '@mui/lab/AdapterLuxon';
import LocalizationProvider from '@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import TextInput from "../TextInput/TextInput";

export const TIME_INPUT_FORMAT = "hh:mm a";

export const TimeInput = ({name, label, defaultValue, ...props}) => {
    const {control, register, formState: {errors}} = useFormContext();
    return (
        <Controller
            name={name}
            control={control}
            render={({field}) => (
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
                    <TimePicker
                        {...field}
                        inputFormat={TIME_INPUT_FORMAT}
                        renderInput={(props) => (
                            <TextInput
                                label={label}
                                defaultValue={defaultValue}
                                {...register(name)}
                                error={!!errors[name]}
                                helperText={errors[name] ? errors[name]?.message : ''}
                                {...props}
                            />
                        )}
                        {...props}
                    />
                </LocalizationProvider>
            )}
        />
    )
};

TimeInput.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    defaultValue: PropTypes.string
};

TimeInput.defaultProps = {
    label: "",
    defaultValue: "",
};

export default TimeInput;
```

which both use Luxon as the dateAdpater. The form works well and the values update fine. However, when handling my onSubmit, I am reading the form values and sending them back to the backend and my DatePicker and TimePicker are returning their values in the following format:

Date: "Sat Nov 13 2021 23:36:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

Time: "2021-11-02T18:30:03.317-04:00"

where the date is correctly set for the date and the time is correctly set for the time. I assumed the values coming from reading the values on the UI would return in a Luxon Date format or at least be easily parsable into a Luxon Date format. This way I could combine and format them to a datetime string such that the DB will accept them.

I understand I could manually parse the date string but I assumed there must be a better way to do this. However, I have searched for hours looking through Luxon and MUI docs and have not had any luck.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

As an example:

I take the two form values and pass them into a function like:

```
export const formatDateAndTimeToDatetimeField = (date, time) => {
    const dateParsed = {Something here};
    const timeParsed = {Something here};
    const datetime = Datetime.fromObject({
        year: dateParsed.year,
        month: dateParsed.month,
        day: dateParsed.day,
        hour: timeParsed.hour,
        minute: timeParsed.minute,
    });
    return datetime.toUTC().toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss+00:00");
}
```

where I can't quite figure out the {Something here} without writing code to explicitly parse the string. I assume there must be a more robust/easier solution from Luxon but I couldn't find it anywhere

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello yes there is a better way to parse the string i was also confused about how MUI handle DateTime input.
In fact once you get the `date` as string in your form before submit it to the backend, you can just parse the string with luxon to get a full DateTime object and the apply all format you want.

```js
import {DateTime} from 'luxon';


const Submit = (data) => {
   const date = DateTime.fromISO(data.date);
   // now you can use date object like a normal luxon DT object
   const payload = date.toSQLDate()
   // here request your backend with the payload
}
```

and my DatePicker component look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useController } from 'react-hook-form';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { DatePicker as MuiDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import MuiTextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { AdapterLuxon } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon';

const DatePicker = ({ label, control, name, renderInput, inputFormat }) => {
  const {
    field: { onChange, value },
  } = useController({ control, name, defaultValue: '' });

  const changeHandler = (value) => {
    onChange(value.toISO());
  };

  const renderInputDefault = (props) => <MuiTextField {...props} />;
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
      <MuiDatePicker
        value={value}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        renderInput={renderInput ? renderInput : renderInputDefault}
        label={label}
        disableMaskedInput
        inputFormat={inputFormat}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};
```

Hope it will help :)